# Mysql: Need to find all gaps in 24Hr, But displays only times between busy times -

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I use the below code to find empty times in 24 hours. code works well, but only shows gaps between some times.
for example, if we have a busy time from 19:00 to 19:40 and another from 20:30 to 21:00, we need to show the below result:

```
free_time_start   free_time_end
00:00:00          19:40:00
19:40:00          20:30:00
21:00:00          24:00:00
```

But the result is :

```
19:40:00    20:30:00
```

means the results show only time between the busy times. Do not show before and after them from the beginning of the day or to the end of the day.

My Code :

```
SELECT
    last_time + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE AS free_time_start,
    time  - INTERVAL 0 MINUTE AS  free_time_end
FROM (
    SELECT
        sc.*,lag(time+ INTERVAL perclocko MINUTE ) OVER (PARTITION BY courses_id ORDER BY time) AS last_time
        
    FROM
        students_courses sc 
) s
WHERE last_time < time;
```

NOTE: per clock is the duration per class.

I tried to add fake rows to the query like this :

```
Union 0,0,0,0,'00:00:00',30,1
```

but that does not work.

Comment: Please publish table definitions and sample data as text.

Comment: Server cannot return the data which absent. 00:00:00 and 24:00:00 are not present in your data, these values must be added as static values.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), see #5 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO sample:

```
CREATE TABLE timeslots (
  time_start TIME,
  time_end TIME,
  CHECK ('00:00:00' <= time_start),
  CHECK (time_start < time_end),
  CHECK (time_end <= '24:00:00')
);
INSERT INTO timeslots VALUES 
('19:00', '19:40'), ('20:30', '21:00');
SELECT * FROM timeslots;
```

| time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- |
| 19:00:00 | 19:40:00 |
| 20:30:00 | 21:00:00 |

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT '00:00:00' slot, 1 weight
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '24:00:00', -1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT time_start, -1 FROM timeslots
  UNION ALL
  SELECT time_end, 1 FROM timeslots
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT slot, SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY slot) cum_sum
  FROM cte1
  ),
cte3 AS (
  SELECT slot, SUM(cum_sum) OVER (ORDER BY slot) cum_sum
  FROM cte2
  )
SELECT MIN(slot) free_time_start,
       MAX(slot) free_time_end 
FROM cte3 
GROUP BY cum_sum;
```

| free_time_start | free_time_end |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 19:00:00 |
| 19:40:00 | 20:30:00 |
| 21:00:00 | 24:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C0JD-Lda)

The query assumes that there is no overlapping timeslots.